# Azure AD graph API using on-premise domain

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs

I am trying to access the `Azure AD` graph API. I have successfully added users to my test environment (`ADFS`) and changed their domain to `{mytestdomain}.onmicrosoft.com`. The password synchronization using `Azure AD Connect` works.

Now I have setup the production environment (including `ADFS`) accordingly and I am now synchronizing the users, but obviously can't change the domains to `{mydomain}.onmicrosoft.com.` The users now have `{mydomain}.net` and I am synchronizing the users to a verified domain in `Azure AD`.

When trying to access
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mydomain}.net/oauth2/token`
using the following (yes, I know that `grant_type` is not recommended, but that's not the point)

```
grant_type: password
username: {user}@{mydomain}.net
password: XXXX
resource: https://graph.windows.net
client_id: {Guid}
```

I get:

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials.
>   AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password

If I use an administrator like `admin@{mydomain}.onmicrosoft.com` it works fine.

In the Azure portal I have tried changing the primary domain from `{mydomain}.onmicrosoft.com` to `{mydomain}.net`, but it does not make a difference.

It says in the management portal:

> "To configure {mydomain} for federated sign-on to your Azure Active Directory, run Azure AD Connect on your local network."

Does that apply when using the graph API as well? Do I have to setup federation on my local network or is there another way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the azure portal I have tried changing the primary domain from
>   `{mydomain}.onmicrosoft.com` to `{mydomain}.net`, but it does not make a
>   difference.

I'm not clear the details of your Syncing steps. Besides verified you custom domain in Azure AD, you also need some other configurations, like **Azure AD sign-in configuration**. You can see more details in [this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-user-signin#azure-ad-sign-in-configuration)

> Does that apply when using the graph api as well? Do I have to setup
>   federation on my local network or is there another way around?

Yes, Since you're using ADFS, you need to use [Federated SSO (with Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-user-signin#federation-that-uses-a-new-or-existing-farm-with-ad-fs-in-windows-server-2012-r2) to allows your users to sign in to both cloud and on-premises resources by using the same passwords.

[image]

You can also see more details about Azure AD Connect user sign-in options in [this official document](http://Azure%20AD%20Connect%20user%20sign-in%20options).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, @ danskov .Using Azure AD Connect to set up a hybrid identity authentication may be not easy, if you have any process , please don't be shy to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for some links. That really helped me in the right direction. I am in the proces of setting up the federation now. I will check back later.

Comment: Hi,@danskov. One quetion, One ansewr. I suggest you open a new question, I believe communities would help you.