# Verify ADFS federation with Azure AD

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, adfs3.0

In relation to this question:
[Azure AD graph API using on-premise domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333314/azure-ad-graph-api-using-on-premise-domain/47342535)

I have set up an federation between the on premise ADFS and Azure AD using the Azure AD connect tool. In the last step of the verification I ran into this:

[image: Imgur]

I believe that it is because the ADFS needs to somehow be exposed to the internet. Probably using an proxy server. In the Azure portal the Domain is now marked as federated. I have tried to do a post to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domain}/oauth2/token, it works when I use xx.onmicrosoft.com users created directly an the Azure AD domain. When I use a user@{domain} user syncronized from the on premise AD I still get

""error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password....." like I did before I set up the federation. I would actually expect to be somehow redirected to the on premise login screen

So two questions:

1. Is it nessesary to have the ADFS exposed to the internet via a proxy for the federation not to fail?
2. How can I properly test logging in to Azure AD using the on premise user?

Thanks in advance :)

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to my own questions.

1. What I was trying to do was have my customers users in my azure ad domain. What that means is that the customer cant have their own Azure AD or office 365 as the domain can only exist once on Azure. So this is not at solution.
2. Use https://{domain}/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon